# Can an Action use bindFromRequest() method without no submitting?

Tags: playframework

I regard `bindFromRequest()` method as the method which assigns some values from a form in web page toward a certain class for containing these values as its fields. However, in my guiding book I saw an Action has `bindFromRequest()` method although the action corresponds with first access, which means the Action has the method despite no submission.

In conclusion, it is possible and I already conformed it, but considering the meaning of the method, is it acceptable?

Please give me your perspective toward the method.

This is view's code.

```
@(msg: String, form1: Form[Application.FindForm], datas: List[Message])

@main("Sample Page") {
    <h1>delete data</h1>
    <p>@msg</p>
    @helper.form(action = routes.Application.find) {

        @(helper.inputText(
            field = form1("input")
            ))

        <input type="submit">
    }

    <hr>
    <p>@datas</p>

}
```

This is the action's code

```
//Finder用の内部クラス
    public static class FindForm {
        @Required 
        public String input;

    }

    public static Result find() {
        Form<FindForm> f = new Form(FindForm.class).bindFromRequest();
        List<Message> datas = null;
        if(!(f.hasErrors())) {
            datas = Message.find.where().like()
        }
        return ok(find.render("serching", f, datas));
    }
```

Moreover, routing is 
GET      /find        controllers.Application.find()

Comment: Could you please add the code for the example you are talking about?

Comment: I'm so sorry for my super delay.   I edited my question, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bindFromRequest` will bind query string variables as well from form-encoded body variables. Looking at the Scala source at: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala, `bindFromRequest` is defined like this:

```
def bindFromRequest()(implicit request: play.api.mvc.Request[_]): Form[T] = {
  bindFromRequest {
    (request.body match {
      case body: play.api.mvc.AnyContent if body.asFormUrlEncoded.isDefined => body.asFormUrlEncoded.get
      // other matches elided
      case _ => Map.empty[String, Seq[String]]
    }) ++ request.queryString
  }
}
```

Note that in addition to matching variables defined in the body, it loads those defined in the queryString as well `request.queryString`.

So from that perspective it makes sense that your FindForm (assuming it contains filter-like variables) is bound from the request.

Keep in mind that an `Action` may handle request variables not defined in the `routes` file. Let's say you have a controller:

```
object MyController extends Controller {
  def index(limit: Int): Action[AnyContent] = ???
  def find: Action[AnyContent] = ???
}
```

and associated `routes` file:

```
GET /my/index   MyController.index(limit: Int)
GET /my/find    MyController.find
```

The `index` route requires a query string parameter `limit`, which is explicitly defined in the routes file. Despite this, you could have the `index` route do something with a `page` parameter if you passed it in the URL like: http://localhost:9000/my/index?limit=1&page=2. The `find` route could also accept additional query string parameters such as filter variables.

To process additional query string values in the Action, you would do something like:

```
def index(limit: Int) = Action { request =>
  val qs: Map[String, Seq[String]] = request.queryString
  // do something with qs
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.      Actually, I am not sure of your meaning clearly.       What is the meaning of form-encoded body variables?     Moreover, I couldn't understand your last sentence, " an Action may handle request variables not defined in the routes file".    What do you want to tell me?

Comment: @KazuyaTomita I edited my answer to explain " an Action may handle request variables not defined in the routes file"


As for form-encoded body variables, I mean, when you POST a form, an HTTP request is sent that encodes the form values in the body of the request and the content type of the message is `www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.    However, I'm not still clear of your intention.   First, you said 'bindFromRequest' bind query string variables.   Isn't it 'getQueryString' that bind query string variables?     And why did you mention Action handle request variables not defined in routes file as well as  variables defined in it?  Is it relevant to my question of the meaning of 'bindFromRequest'?

Comment: Sorry, can you link me to `getQueryString`?

Comment: String msg = request().getQueryString("msg").    By using this, you can use the query variable from parameter at end of URL.     If you access the URL "http://localhost:9000?msg=hello, the String variable "msg" has the value of "hello".    Make sense?

Comment: Ah, I use Scala so I'm not familiar with the Java API. `getQueryString` does not _bind_ variables like `bindFromRequest` does. I believe `bindFromRequest` binds query string variables using the form, but `getQueryString` will give you a raw `Map`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.    However, even though I used POST method to pass values to a server side, which means a client side passed values written in the HTTP request's body not the query string, the method "bindFromRequest" works well.  Despite no query string, it can work.  You said "bindFromRequest will bind query string variables as well from form-encoded body variables ."   What do you mean by that?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the source of `bindFromRequest`, which will hopefully demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I can't still understand well, I don't know Scala at all.( I know I have to study).  However, I had thought about it very much.  And my comprehension is like this, please check.      bindFromRequset can bind both query string variables and form-encoded those in HTTP body to any Form class prepared by programer. And the difference between bindFromRequst and getQueryString is return values, namely, bindFromRequest returns Form class and getQueryString does Map class.  Am I right?